# Net core 2.0 - Razor Pages partial view with business itself (not MVC)

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a sidebar view as a partial view. I want to insert it into main page.
Sidebar read some images url from database and show it into html page.
In main page, I used this code to insert sidebar:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("Shared/_Sidebar")
```

Side bar cshtml page:

```
@model MyWeb.Pages.Shared._SidebarModel
...
```

But it raise error:

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'MyWeb.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MyWeb.Pages.Shared._SidebarModel'
```

I have research this issue, and get the answer is, must pass model from parent page, like this:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("Shared/_Sidebar", Model.Urls)
```

If so, the parent page must handle the business of the child page. So, if I do not insert the sidebar into the main page, but to another page, I have to remove the code on the main page, and add the business code to the new page, and so on... Sidebar can not handle its own business.
In MVC, we can use RenderAction to insert a partial view with its action to handler business logic. But I have not found a way to do this in RazorPages.
Anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways including passing it as a `ViewData`. I found injection to be one of the cleanest ways:

Initialize your `_SidebarModel` as a service. This can be a scoped if you plan on using any scoped service with it (like `DBContext`). You can use this in your startup class:

```
services.AddSingleton<_SidebarModel>();
```

Or if you would like to initialize it here:

```
services.AddSingleton<>(new _SidebarModel { });
```

Now, instead of `@model MyWeb.Pages.Shared._SidebarModel`, you can use:

```
@inject MyWeb.Pages.Shared._SidebarModel MyModel
```

You can always inject and control the model from your view models as well.

You can add some basic functionality using of page view models with a class like this:

```
public class InjectablePage : PageModel
{
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;

    public InjectablePage(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
        if (httpContext.Request.Method == "GET") OnGet();
    }

    public virtual void OnGet() { }

}
```

You can extend this instead of `PageModel` in `_SidebarModel`

Comment: But where is the code behind you will use to handle events, like OnPostAsync, onGetAsync..?

Comment: those functions are page related, i don't see much point in adding it to view models. it is against logic. the best approach would be to create your own view model class that contains the whole content including the sidebar and extending it. 
either ways, i have provided an example for something you can do with injection

Comment: I found a solution is use viewcomponent instead of partial view. But viewcomponent is only handler get data, not post data yet

Comment: view component provides you a `Request` property you can use